# how to pass byte[] parameter using json to wcf data services

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf-data-services

I have one Data Service.Using Json how can pass `byte[]` parameter to the one of the method in Data Services?

Comment: You'll probably have to send it as a Base64- or Hex-encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

As per http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/json-format, JSON uses literal forms of EDM types.  The EDM type is Edm.Binary, with literal form binary'...'

Comment: can You check my code on link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120916/getting-error-while-passing-byte-parameter-using-json-to-wcf-data-services